# Sklearn OneClassSVM with RandomizedSearchCV: "ValueError: 'f' is not in list"

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to train a one-class SVM for anomaly detection. I want to use random search for tuning my model.

I set the range for my model's parameters. However, I get this error and I failed to find its cause.
ValueError: 'f' is not in list

After loading my data and the relevant libraries. I specify the SVM model details as shown:

```
param_dist = {"kernel":"rbf",
              "gamma" : np.logspace(-9, 3, 13),
              "nu" : np.linspace(0.01, 0.99, 99)}
clf = svm.OneClassSVM()

clf_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator  = clf, param_distributions = param_dist,  scoring = "accuracy")
```

It is worth noting that my training data is of size (500000,5).

When I try to train the model,

```
clf_cv.fit(Xtrain)
```

I get the following error

```
*My directory*\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py in _dense_fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed)
    252                 cache_size=self.cache_size, coef0=self.coef0,
    253                 gamma=self._gamma, epsilon=self.epsilon,
--> 254                 max_iter=self.max_iter, random_seed=random_seed)
    255 
    256         self._warn_from_fit_status()

sklearn\svm\libsvm.pyx in sklearn.svm.libsvm.fit()

ValueError: 'f' is not in list
```

I tried to track down the cause of the error but I still couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your `param_distributions`. As stated by the documentation for [RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html):

> param_distributions : dict
>   Dictionary with parameters names (string) as keys and distributions or lists of parameters to try. Distributions must provide a rvs method for sampling (such as those from scipy.stats.distributions). If a list is given, it is sampled uniformly.

Essentially all of the values in the `param_distributions` need to be lists or an rvs method. Therefore, in this case the value for `kernel` should be `['rbf']` instead of `'rbf'`.

The reason you see `ValueError: 'f' is not in list` is that the string 'rbf' is split into 'r', 'b', 'f' and when you call fit 'f' is passed as the value for kernel. In the internals of svm, [`sklearn.svm.libsvm.fit`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/svm/libsvm.pyx#L53-L244) is called. There you can see on line 170 is a check that looks for the kernel in a list of available kernels. That is where the error is actually coming from.